# Is css class binding safe?

Tags: knockout.js, xss

I have a tiny widget that client websites embed using an iframe. I would like the clients to be able to specify the css class as below where widgetStyle is provided via the url, something like http://acme.widget.com/#/widgetStyle

```
<body data-bind="attr: { 'class': widgetStyle }">
  <!-- Content -->
</body>
```

My question is: Is this safe? Is knockout guaranteed to escape it correctly to avoid XSS and the like? Is it safe in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. The reason is CSS assigning is done not by modifying HTML as a string, but by modifying the HTML DOM properties. So, knockout does class assigning though the code `node.className=newClass`. So you can put whatever you want in the `newClass` without any additional escaping.

And a little off topic. You can make your code cleaner, if you use `css` binding of knockout:

`<body data-bind="css: widgetStyle">`